# Composite function of $R$-module

Tags: modules, function-and-relation-composition, abstract-algebra

Let $M$, $N$, $P$ be $R$-module and functions $f:M\rightarrow N$, $g:M\rightarrow N$, $h:N\rightarrow P$, $k:P\rightarrow M$, which need not be homomorphisms. Define $f+g:M\rightarrow N$ by $(f+g)(a)=f(a)+g(a)$. It is easy to see that to have

$$h\circ(f+g)=h\circ f+h\circ g$$

$h$ needs to be a homomorphism. However, to have

$$(f+g)\circ k=f\circ k+g\circ k$$

why $k$ needs to be a homomorphism? It looks like the equality holds for arbitrary $k$.

Comment: Why dobyou think that it needs to be a homomorphism?

Comment: (what happens is that no one really cares about the maps which are not homomorphisms...)

Comment: Because I am reading a book and it says "if k is a homomorphism, then (f+g)k = fk + gk".

Comment: So k needs not be a homomorphism?

Comment: So k needs not be a homomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$No, it need not be a homomorphism.

For example, suppose that $R=\mathbb Z$, let $M=N=P=\ZZ/2\ZZ$, the abelian group of order two, let the two morphisms $f$, $g:\ZZ/2\ZZ\to\ZZ/2\ZZ$ be the identity map of $\ZZ/2\ZZ$ and let $k:\ZZ/2\ZZ\to\ZZ/2\ZZ$ be the constant map with value $1$. Then $(f+g)\circ k=f\circ k+g\circ k$, but $k$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: More generally, pick $n>1$ and $1\leq m<n$, let $M=N=P=\ZZ/n\ZZ$, let $f:M\to N$ be multiplication by $m$ and $g:M\to N$ be multiplication by $n-m$, and let $k:P\to M$ be **any** function.

Comment: To add drama, let $M$, $N$ and $P$ be **any** modules, let $k:P\to M$ be **any** function, and let $f$, $g:M\to N$ be both the zero map (you can also take $f:M\to N$ to be **any** function and $g:x\in M\mapsto -f(x)\in N$).